# How to load(pytorch) bigger dataset in to GPU and do mini batch training?

Tags: gpu, pytorch, batchsize

as we know, batch size affects training accuracy. (smaller batch size with higher acc.). but using smaller batch size also means longer training time. 
Assume there are larger memory in GPU (ex. Nvidia RTX 2080 with 8GB memory on GPU). Is there a way to load bigger data size into GPU and train with smaller dataset, in order to minimize the data access between CPU and GPU also get the better accuracy with mini training batch?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "load bigger data size into GPU and train with smaller dataset"? Is your dataset too big to fit into your GPU?

Comment: for example, if I set batch_size = 10, I can get better accuracy result but the whole training process takes longer to train the whole 450 Epochs, since GPU only load batch size 10 each time. If set batch_size to 32/ 64 /128, the training process can be much quickly, but with lower accuracy.  So if I can load bigger data batch(128/256/512) in to GPU memory, but still train model with 10 batch_size. then we can get higher acc. with shorter training time.